# What if you could create not-nullable reference type?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, nullable, non-nullable

**Have you ever** faced the need of informing anyone who uses your code and passes some reference typed parameters to **not pass the null**? You definitely have. And you should have thrown exceptions for each "bad" variable your code cannot work with.

Now, let's imagine you have created this struct:

```
public struct NotNullable<T> where T : class
{
    // Backing field for the value. Guaranteed to return not null.
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_value == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Value is not initialized.");

            return _value;
        }
    }

    // Easy both-ways convertible.
    public static implicit operator T(NotNullable<T> notNullable)
    {
        return notNullable.Value;
    }
    public static implicit operator NotNullable<T>(T value)
    {
        return new NotNullable<T>(value);
    }

    // These members are overridden.
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is NotNullable<T>)
        {
            return Value.Equals(((NotNullable<T>)obj).Value);
        }

        return Value.Equals(obj);
    }

    public NotNullable(T value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }
}
```

Usage of such a structure:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NotNullable<string> a = "Hello World!";

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine((string)a);
        Console.WriteLine((object)a);
        Console.WriteLine((NotNullable<string>)a);

        // Produces fine outputs.


        var b = default(NotNullable<string>); 
        Console.WriteLine(b); // Throws an exception of non-initialized field.
    }
}
```

You could also make your methods to receive non-nullable reference typed parameters:

```
List<Tree> treeList;

public void CreateTree(NotNullable<Tree> tree)
{
    // Assume you cannot have the list contain nulls.
    treeList.Add(tree); // No null-checks required.
}
```

What could possibly be wrong in a such useful opposite to [`Nullable<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) struct?

Comment: How is your non-initialized exception any different from a null reference exception?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it per se, however, your implementation should be changed: The exception should be thrown when *creating* the `NotNullable` instance and not when accessing `Value`. Because in that case *your* code doesn't throw an exception. It's the code of the consumer and he is responsible for passing a non-null value.

Comment: @asawyer in my example of adding the parameter in a `List` there will be no null reference exception.

Comment: @AgentFire Sure, but you've just swapped one exception for another. And in your code it has to check whether the field is initialized *every* time you access `NotNullable<T>.Value`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth that is impossible since I cannot define parameterless struct constructors.

Comment: @AgentFire: Make it a class then.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Cannot be done either. In the case, the class will be nulled too, which makes the whole point useless.

Comment: @AgentFire: Hm, that's a good point actually. You still can perform the check in the existing constructor for the cases where the consumer uses the struct as intended: Fail Fast.

Comment: As much as I would like to see this sort of thing supported in the language directly, I don't see this as a good substitute.

Comment: @AgentFire: I think you have come to the answer yourself: your type must be a struct, which means people can create default values of it, which means you cannot enforce the "field is never null" invariant at construction (that would actually be useful). So you are reduced to enforcing the non-nullity on access, which is kind of pointless as you could easily do the same with e.g. an extension method `ThrowIfNull(this object testSubject)`. End result: you gain less typing where non-nullity needs to be enforced at the expense of consistency. Bad.

Comment: @Jon I have a `ThrowIfDefault` that works for structs as well. http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/object/throwifdefault

Comment: @p.s.w.g: This type of struct would be silly for a mutable data type, but if `String` had been a struct which held a reference to a `HeapString` object, then `default(String)` would have been a valid representation of an empty string (as had been the case under COM).  Performance could have been equivalent to existing code if the CLR used special rules for boxing/unboxing `HeapString` (much as it does for `Nullable<T>`).  Code that *wants* a nullable string type could use `HeapString`.

Comment: @Jon: If the struct only holds references to objects that will never be exposed to code that could mutate them, one wouldn't have to throw any sort of exception.  It could behave as though it held a reference to a default-valued object.  That *could* be useful; the only ugly thing about it would be the lack of any means of specifying that conversion to a reference type shouldn't box the struct, but instead do something else (e.g. call a custom conversion function associated with the structure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fail to see how this is advantageous to throwing `ArgumentNullException`. As the matter of fact, I'd rather do this:

```
public void Foo(MyClass item, MyClass2 item2)
{
    if (item == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

    if (item2 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item2");
}
```

This way I let the programmer know which parameter was bad. With `NotNullable<T>` I imagine it would look like this:

```
public void Foo(NotNullable<MyClass> item, NotNullable<MyClass> item2) { ... }

Foo((NotNullable<MyClass>)myVar1, (NotNullable<MyClass2>)myVar2);
```

Now I get `"Value is not initialized."` thrown in my face. Which one?

Comment: Change `Foo((NotNullable<MyClass>)myVar1, (NotNullable<MyClass2>)myVar2);` to `Foo(mayVar1, myVar2);`.

Comment: You could explain what variable of type is null. Like `"Value of type MyClass is not initialized."`.

Comment: So, if I provide a .dll for someone else, his project needs to convert all his types to `NotNullable`?

Comment: @AgentFire Both params could be of the same type. If you have `AddEmployee(Person newEmployee, Person hiringManager, Person hrManager)` and one of your arguments was null, there would be no way to tell which one.

Comment: But what if cake was a lie..